# problems at nested hierarchy view using storyboard in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode-storyboard, nested-views

I'm beginner at Swift, so currently i organize most part of my app using storyboard.

I want to construct some view scrollable that contains textField and pickerView.

and each of them is stacked View, and then it is child view of view A.
and view A is child view of scrollView.

help you to understand more, i'll attach my app structure.

[image: App construct]

Anyway, when i run my apps, it represent well i want to achieve, however, coudn't get any touch reaction.

keyboard isn't popup when i touch textField, pickerView scroll isn't working. I think it's because of nested view, but have no idea how to solve.

plz help! And also glad give some advice learn Swift. 
Thx in advance.

*** edit 1) attach my code ***

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: 
UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet var outerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statePicker: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var innerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameInputer: UITextField!

    let states = ["Alaska", "Arkansas", "Alabama", "California", "Maine", "New York"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
        for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
            scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: scrollViewHeight)
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 20, 0)

        statePicker.dataSource = self
        statePicker.delegate = self

        statePicker.isExclusiveTouch = true
        scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = false

        innerView.sendSubview(toBack: outerView)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return states.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return states[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        statePicker.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

*** EDIT 2 : attach my story board ***
[image: my stoy board]

Comment: Learn about UITextFieldDelegate and UIPickerViewDelegate , google it

Comment: @user1000 thx for answering. I didn't implement UITextFieldDelegate, however, implement UIPickerViewDelegate.

So, if pickerView unwrap from its parent View, can handle pickerView. 
But it isnt' working when it's exist for child View of some other Views

Comment: Please show your code so we can help you better

Comment: @user1000 okay, i'll edit my question !

Comment: Follow the same procedure as UIPickerview delegate, add the UITextfieldDelegate methods in the viewcontroller, and also I would say follow this tutorial you will learn about textfields : http://sourcefreeze.com/uitextfield-and-uitextfield-delegate-in-swift/  , if you face problem please ask